# how to read a json in pandas dataframe and change one column value to uppercase and save the json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to read a json file into pandas dataframe. Then, I'm trying to convert one entire column values into uppercase.
The code is below,

```
data = pd.read_json('demo1.json') 
print(data)
print(data[column].str.upper())
print(data)
```

The output is below,

```
          CITY FIRST_NAME  ID LAST_NAME          SSN
0      Waymill  Albertine   1       Jan  515-72-7353
1  Spellbridge   Maryetta   2      Hoyt  515-72-7354
2    Stoneland     Dustin   3    Divina  515-72-7355
3      Fayview      Jenna   4     Sofia  515-72-7356


0        WAYMILL
1    SPELLBRIDGE
2      STONELAND
3        FAYVIEW


Name: CITY, dtype: object
          CITY FIRST_NAME  ID LAST_NAME          SSN
0      Waymill  Albertine   1       Jan  515-72-7353
1  Spellbridge   Maryetta   2      Hoyt  515-72-7354
2    Stoneland     Dustin   3    Divina  515-72-7355
3      Fayview      Jenna   4     Sofia  515-72-7356
```

So, I'm able to print the values as uppercase, but, the whole dataframe isn't changing.

Need some guideline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign back output of `str.upper` function to column with same name for overwrite values or to new name for append new column filled by uppercase values:

```
data['CITY'] = data['CITY'].str.upper()
print (data)
          CITY FIRST_NAME  ID LAST_NAME          SSN
0      WAYMILL  Albertine   1       Jan  515-72-7353
1  SPELLBRIDGE   Maryetta   2      Hoyt  515-72-7354
2    STONELAND     Dustin   3    Divina  515-72-7355
3      FAYVIEW      Jenna   4     Sofia  515-72-7356
```

---

```
data['NEW_CITY'] = data['CITY'].str.upper()
print (data)
          CITY FIRST_NAME  ID LAST_NAME          SSN     NEW_CITY
0      Waymill  Albertine   1       Jan  515-72-7353      WAYMILL
1  Spellbridge   Maryetta   2      Hoyt  515-72-7354  SPELLBRIDGE
2    Stoneland     Dustin   3    Divina  515-72-7355    STONELAND
3      Fayview      Jenna   4     Sofia  515-72-7356      FAYVIEW
```

EDIT:

If need `CITY` column to end of DataFrames columns use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract and then assign to same column name:

```
df['CITY'] = df.pop('CITY').str.upper()
print (df)
  FIRST_NAME  ID LAST_NAME          SSN         CITY
0  Albertine   1       Jan  515-72-7353      WAYMILL
1   Maryetta   2      Hoyt  515-72-7354  SPELLBRIDGE
2     Dustin   3    Divina  515-72-7355    STONELAND
3      Jenna   4     Sofia  515-72-7356      FAYVIEW
```

Comment: please have a look into my output results.. using your code, the column is changing but, the whole dataframe isn't updating.

Comment: @DebrajDas - Added output from your sample data and working nice for me.

Comment: then how to replace the old column with the new.. eg. how to replace CITY with NEW_CITY?

Comment: @DebrajDas - It is second paragraph in answer.

Comment: @DebrajDas - Or do you think first solution and then `df = df.rename(columns={'CITY':'NEW_CITY'})` ?

Comment: Able to solve it.. first create a new column, then dropping the exising one, then again renaming the newly created column to it's previous column name..

data['NEW_CITY'] = data['CITY'].str.upper()
    del data['CITY']
    data = data.rename(columns={'NEW_CITY':'CITY'})
    print(data)

Comment: otherwise `df.rename(columns={'CITY':'NEW_CITY'}, inplace=True)`

Comment: @DebrajDas, you can use `inplace=True`

Comment: @DebrajDas - Added simplier solution with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html)

Comment: @jezrael do you have any idea to change the column order?
in source it was ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, CITY, SSN
but in output it's not same..

Comment: @DebrajDas - You can pass new order like list - `df = df[['ID', 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'CITY', 'SSN']]`

Comment: @jezrael would be able to help me on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57923488/how-to-merge-multiple-data-frame-objs-into-a-single-data-frame-obj-with-given-co?noredirect=1#comment102266393_57923488

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to create a new column as you mentioned along with converting to uppercase then try below.

`DataFrame.assign()` + `str.upper()`

```
df = df.assign(NEW_CITY=data['CITY'].str.upper())
```

In case you want to have only the `NEW_CITY` and remove the old one ie `CITY` then you can try..

```
df = df.assign(NEW_CITY=data['CITY'].str.upper()).drop(columns=['CITY'])
```

To retain the column name back using `df.rename()`

```
df.rename(columns={'NEW_CITY':'CITY'}, inplace=True)
```