# How to merge multiple data frame objs into a single data frame obj with given conditions in pandas/python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The POST request I'm sending to my python backend service is as below,

```
{
    "updated_by": "969823826",
    "relation_on": "ID",
    "join_type": "inner",
    "sources": [
    {
        "json_obj": "path/demo8.json",
        "columns": [
            "ID",
            "FIRST_NAME",
            "LAST_NAME"
        ]
    },
    {
        "json_obj": "path/demo1.json",
        "columns": [
            "ID",
            "CITY",
            "SSN"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So, I'm trying to merge as INNER JOIN the two sources objects based on ID column.

I'm merging **ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME** from **FILE1** with **ID, CITY, SSN** from **FILE2**.

By using a static method I'm able to do this.

Here's my code sample for static method,

```
import json
import pandas as pd

file1 = "path\\demo1.json"
file2 = "path\\demo3.json"

df1 = pd.read_json(file1)
df2 = pd.read_json(file2)

#merge with specific columns and conditions
new_df = pd.merge(df1[['ID', 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME']], df2[['ID', 'CITY', 'SSN']], on='ID', how="inner")   

#merging without any common column
df1['tmp'] = 1
df2['tmp'] = 1     

new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['tmp'])
new_df = new_df.drop('tmp', axis=1)

new_df.to_json("path\\merge-json.json", orient='records')
```

Now, if I want to merge the data frames in a dynamic way by using for loop, I'm having some trouble.

Tried several options, but, I think I'm not going into the right direction.

Here's the code for dynamic method,

```
updated_by = request.get_json()['updated_by']
relation_on = request.get_json()['relation_on']
join_type = request.get_json()['join_type']

sources = request.get_json()['sources']
sources = str(sources).replace("'", '"')
sources = json.loads(sources)

for sources_key, sources_value in enumerate(sources):
    print(sources_key, sources_value)
```

Till this point for the above code, it's executing and I'm able to view the objects as the below,

```
0 {'ctl_key': '969823826demo8txt', 'json_obj': 'path/demo8.json', 'columns': ['ID', 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME']}
1 {'ctl_key': '969823826demo1csv', 'json_obj': 'path/demo1.json', 'columns': ['ID', 'CITY', 'SSN']}
```

Now, my initial approaches were to create new dataframes based on the file inputs and then merge those two data frames and create the final one.

**Need a JSON obj as output as below,**

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "FIRST_NAME": "Albertine",
    "LAST_NAME": "Jan",
    "CITY": "Waymill",
    "SSN": "515-72-7353"
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "FIRST_NAME": "Maryetta",
    "LAST_NAME": "Hoyt",
    "CITY": "Spellbridge",
    "SSN": "515-72-7354"
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "FIRST_NAME": "Dustin",
    "LAST_NAME": "Divina",
    "CITY": "Stoneland",
    "SSN": "515-72-7355"
  },
  {
    "ID": 4,
    "FIRST_NAME": "Jenna",
    "LAST_NAME": "Sofia",
    "CITY": "Fayview",
    "SSN": "515-72-7356"
  }
]
```

Anyone any guidelines, please...

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: @vbrises I've edited the summary including the desired output needed.

Comment: You have 'ID' columns, then why not merge on that column?

Comment: Yes, I've one common column.. and I can merge both the files based on the given condition.. but, able to do it in a static way.. I've also attached the code for that.. Facing issue while accessing the JSON request and making the dataframe using loop.. PS: I'm new to python

Answer (score 0):

When I outer join dataframes I like to use `pd.set_index` to the column I want to join on then use `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`.
I think that should work for this case.

Comment: regarding join, I'm not facing any issues.. My question is how to iterate necessary objects from the post request and create the data frame dynamically..